# How to start skype with Android browser

Tags: android, skype

As the title, I add 'skype:name?call' in the href attribute of 'a' tag.
Then try to visit this page with my android(4.0) browser, but the skype client is not called after clicking this link.

BTW, it works well on iPhone.

Have no idea about the reason and thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is probably that skype for android does not supports this

Comment: wow.. Is there any way to implement it on android??